# Jenkins artifactory plugin not working

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I have a problem using artifactory and jenkins. See the error log below.

My version jenkins : 1.638
My version of artifactory : 3.9.2

Artifactory is working ok and also installed plugin in jenkins and configured. All seems to work ok but when I want to build a project I have the error below.

```
ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. 
Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
**java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven3.extractor.MavenExtractorEnvironment.buildEnvVars(MavenExtractorEnvironment.java:136)**
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:947)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractMavenBuild.java:56)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.getEnvironment(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:165)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:620)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.util.ExtractorUtils.addBuilderInfoArguments(ExtractorUtils.java:157)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven3.extractor.MavenExtractorEnvironment.buildEnvVars(MavenExtractorEnvironment.java:132)
    ... 9 more
project=hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@d90cf1[messenger]
project.getModules()=[hudson.maven.MavenModule@3993ad[messenger/com.jdb.software:messenger][messenger/com.jdb.software:messenger][relativePath:]]
project.getRootModule()=hudson.maven.MavenModule@3993ad[messenger/com.jdb.software:messenger][messenger/com.jdb.software:messenger][relativePath:]
FATAL: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Can you share your job configuration? also which plugin version are you using and which Maven version?

Comment: I am using maven 3.3.3 and artifactory plugin in jenkins 2.4.4

Answer (score 9):

This is actually a bug (since version 2.4.0).

There is a [Jira issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-665) for this (which I guess you opened).

I attached a URL to a snapshot version built on top of the last release (2.4.4) which also contains a fix for you issue.

If you have any issues with the fix or for any feedback you can use the Jira to communicate it.

BTW: There is a work around that you can use - just configure an Artifactory publish task and everything will work.

Comment: @baliman If you found it useful please consider accept this answer (: